# Custom response during falcon middleware exception

Tags: python, middleware, falcon

I'm writing `Falcon` middleware for my application. When i get any errors i want to raise error, break process and return my custom response, that looks like:

```
{
   "status": 503,
   "message": "No Token found. Token is required."
}
```

But standard `Falcon` error implementation does not allow me to set custom fields to my response.

How to solve this problem most properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of time spent, I solved this problem in such interesting way. I put my code in a try/catch block, and when an error is caught I decided not to raise `Falcon` error, and just tried to write `return` keyword after setting response status and body, because the method is `void`, so it does not return anything. Now it looks like:

```
resp.status = falcon.HTTP_403
resp.body = body

return
```

Answer (score 5):

I was still looking for an example and here is for anyone who still need it:

```
from falcon.http_error import HTTPError

class MyHTTPError(HTTPError):

    """Represents a generic HTTP error.
    """

    def __init__(self, status, error):
        super(MyHTTPError, self).__init__(status)
        self.status = status
        self.error = error

    def to_dict(self, obj_type=dict):
        """Returns a basic dictionary representing the error.
        """
        super(MyHTTPError, self).to_dict(obj_type)
        obj = self.error
        return obj
```

using:

```
error = {"error": [{"message": "Auth token required", "code": "INVALID_HEADER"}]}

raise MyHTTPError(falcon.HTTP_400, error)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create custom exception class explained in falcon docs, search for add_error_handler

```
class RaiseUnauthorizedException(Exception):
    def handle(ex, req, resp, params):
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_401
        response = json.loads(json.dumps(ast.literal_eval(str(ex))))
        resp.body = json.dumps(response)
```

Add custom exception class to falcon API object

```
api = falcon.API()
api.add_error_handler(RaiseUnauthorizedException)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
raise falcon.HTTPError(falcon.HTTP_503, 'No Token found. Token is required.')
```